# WordPress MU | Can current user edit this site options?

Tags: security, wordpress

I am building a WordPress MU service, that allowing users to register sites and manage these sites only from front end via AJAX.

In main site, I have register a domain in the form of `http://www.my-site.com/edit-site/55/` that display a form with the site options.

The problem is that the above method creates security issues, because some user may start change site ids at the end of the URL and reach the site options of other members.

So, is there a way to check if the current user has the right to update the options of the given site ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this link,

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

current_user_can() function will resolve your problem I think.